# Calling Functions From Past Frames in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm having a problem with using functions from previous frames.  I know my coding is crude, but I don't know how to use classes and external AS files, so I would appreciate it if someone could help me without using classes and whatnot.

The problem I'm having is that I have a level of my game on a certain frame, and then the next level on another frame.  The problem is that on my second level is that when I call the event listeners from the previous level and frame, I can move left and right but my jumping no longer works.

Here is the link to my relevant level 1 code: http://pastebin.com/Ftkj36Wc

Here is my level 2 code: http://pastebin.com/NUSE3A02

As I said earlier, my left and right movement works just fine, so I don't quite know what's going wrong.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of level 1 if you do this :

```
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
```

Key input will no longer work in level 2.

Either remove those 2 from the clearLevel function or add event listeners again in level 2 to handle key input.

Comment: If you check my level 2 code, I have added these in.  This is why my player can move L and R, but for some reason jumping does not work.  I appreciate your input.

Comment: What about the state of the isGrounded variable? That has to be reset to true or false when you start the next level?

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help either.  For some reason the up button works when moving up ladders, but simply does not for jumping.